# SwiftUI List Showing as Blank for non-empty List

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to create a simple list view in SwiftUI however, it shows up as blank (pictured below) no matter how many objects are in the array. If I get rid of the list, it will show the elements of the array. I know for a fact that the array is **not** empty. Any recommendations on how to fix it.

This is my code"

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                if(leaderboard.isEmpty) {
                    
                    VStack {
                        Text("No Entries Yet :(")
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                    }
                } else {
                    ScrollView {
                        List {
                            ForEach(leaderboard.asArray(), id: \.self) { score in
                                Text("\(score)")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Leaderboard")
        }
    }
```

Here is what the view currently shows:
[image: Picture of SwiftUI preview where the screen where list should be is blank]

Also, bonus points if you can help me make it so the `Text("No Entries Yet :( ")` is centered vertically within the view.

Comment: You don't need a `ScrollView` if you are using a `List`

Comment: Yeah and IIRC the `ScrollView` becomes extremely tiny in height to the point where you can't see it. Remove both `ScrollView`s.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need either of those `ScrollView`s - If the list is empty you only have the text view.  If the list isn't empty, `List` provides the necessary scroll view.

To vertically centre the text when the list is empty, simply add `Spacer` views above and below:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        let leaderboard:[Int] = [10,20,30,40,100,1999,1393,444]
        NavigationView {
            if(leaderboard.isEmpty) {
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("No Entries Yet :(")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                    Spacer()
                }
            } else {
                List {
                    ForEach(leaderboard, id: \.self) { score in
                        Text("\(score)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Leaderboard")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your list is empty, just add another row without background. Stylish it as you want.

```swift
if rows.isEmpty {
    Text("No records")
        .listRowBackground(EmptyView())
}
```